# Adding contacts to sim card

Tags: java, android, contacts, sim-card

I am trying to add contacts to SIM Card, they seem to be added to the SIM Card but they're only visible after rebooting the device (even to the native People app)..

Here is the code I'm using:

```
final Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://icc/adn");
ContentValues mContentValue = new ContentValues();
mContentValue.put("tag", contactName);
mContentValue.put("number", contactNumber);
getContentResolver().insert(uri, mContentValue);
```

is it a problem with sync'ing the contacts db after creating the contacts? if so, is there a way, may be, to force android to sync the contacts' database with the SIM Card?

---

**EDIT**

Ok, let me explain my problem again. Here is man, who had same problem, but there is no any answer ([when adding contacts to sim card, they are only displayed after rebooting the device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24485735/when-adding-contacts-to-sim-card-they-are-only-displayed-after-rebooting-the-de?rq=1)), so I need to ask it again.
**ACCOUNT_TYPE: com.android.contacts.sim** and **ACCOUNT_NAME: SIM** are wrong for my phone. I got right from **ContactsContract.Settings.CONTENT_URI**: *com.android.huawei.phone - Phone* and *com.android.huawei.sim - sim1*.
Here is my code:

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> op = new ArrayList<>();

Uri simUri = Uri.parse("content://icc/adn");
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("tag", "NAME");
values.put("number", "77777777777");
try {
    Uri uri =  context.getContentResolver().insert(simUri, values);

    int efid = 0,index = 0;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^content://icc/adn/(\\d+)/(\\d+)$*");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(uri.toString());
    if(matcher.matches()) {
        index = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
        efid = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
    }

    ArrayAdapterSpinner.Item item = adapter.getItem(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition());

    op.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "com.android.huawei.sim")
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, "sim1")
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.SYNC1,efid)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.SYNC2,index)
            .build());
    op.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, "NAME")
            .build());
    op.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, "77777777777")
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
            .build());

    try {
        ContentProviderResult[] cprs = context.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, op);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    Log.e("ERROR2", e.toString());
}
```

But result is:
 1. Contact in *icc/adn* is created
 2. Contact in *RawContacts* is created, but **ACCOUNT_TYPE** and
 **ACCOUNT_NAME** are replaced with *com.android.huawei.phone - Phone*

Comment: any news, have the same problem

Comment: Can you please show the query to get the SIM account-type and account-name? You mentioned it's via ContactsContract.Settings.CONTENT_URI, right ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can help

```
 try{
                // add a row to the RawContacts table
         ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
         values.put(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "com.android.contacts.sim");
         values.put(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, "SIM");
         Uri rawContactUri = getContentResolver().insert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, values);

        // get the ID of the newly-added line
 long rawContactId = ContentUris.parseId(rawContactUri);

        // add a "name" line to the Data table, linking it to the new RawContact
        // with the CONTACT_ID column
 values.clear();
 values.put(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId);
 values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
 values.put(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, "Name");
 cr.insert(Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
  getContentResolver().notifyChange(Uri_Here,null); 
        // add a "phone" line to the Data table, linking it to the new RawContact
        // with the CONTACT_ID column
 values.clear();
 values.put(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId);
 values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
 values.put(Phone.NUMBER, "+12345678901");
 values.put(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_MOBILE);
 cr.insert(Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
getContentResolver().notifyChange(Uri_Here,null); 
//New Edit
}
catch(Exception e){
    //exception handling
}
```

Comment: Erhm... my mistake. I have re-explained my issue. Check my edit

Comment: check me new edit ....getContentResolver().notifyChange(simUri, null);  add this so that it appears immediately.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work... I added contact to "icc/adn" and notified changes for "icc/adn" uri. Result: contact added to "icc/adn" but didn't appear to device storage.